# Draw circle on rectangle

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, drawrect

I have UIView class and in method I want to draw first rectangles and sometimes circle

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if ([WhatToDraw isEqual:@"Fields"]) {
        [self DrawField:context];
            }
    if ([WhatToDraw isEqual:@"Ball"]) {
        [self DrawBall:context x:20 y:20];
    }

}

-(void)DrawBall:(CGContextRef)context x:(float) x y:(float) y
{
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGRect  rect = CGRectMake(x, y, 25, 25);
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
}

-(void)DrawField:(CGContextRef)context 
{

    columns = 6;
    float offset = 5;
    float boardWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    float allOffset = (columns + 2) * offset;
    float currentX = 10;
    float currentWidth = (boardWidth - allOffset) / columns;
    float currentHeight = currentWidth;
    self.fieldsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //create a new dynamic button board
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex<columns; columnIndex++) {
        float currentY = offset;
        for (int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<columns; rowIndex++) {
            UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
            //create new field


            CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            CGContextBeginPath(context);
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(currentX, currentY, currentWidth, currentHeight);
            CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
            CGContextFillPath(context);

            currentY = currentY + offset + currentHeight;
        }
        currentX = currentX + offset + currentWidth;
    }  
}
```

I also have method changing what to draw

```
-(void)Draw:(NSString*)Thing
{
    self.WhatToDraw = Thing;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Drawing rectangles (Fields) is ok, but when I click button to draw circle all rectangles disappear and only circle was drawn. 
How can I draw circle on existing rectangle ?

Comment: it is an off-topic but very important part for this post: **[Objective-C Naming Conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/Conventions/Conventions.html)**.

Comment: sry , i am beginner in objective c.. :/

Comment: no probs, when you have time, just read it. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The Problem

Your problem is that when a [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) redraws a region as marked by `setNeedsDisplay` or `setNeedsDisplayInRect` it will completely clear that region before executing your drawing code. This means that unless you draw both the rectangles and circle in a single drawing operation within `drawRect` you will never see the two both drawn in the area you choose to redraw, whether it be the entire view bounds with `setNeedsDisplay` or a specific area with `setNeedsDisplayInRect`.

#### The Solutions

There's no reason why you can't draw both the rectangles and circle each time within `drawRect` and optimise the performance of the drawing by only redrawing the regions necessary with `setNeedsDisplayInRect`.

Alternatively you could break up the content using [CALayers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and have the rectangles in one layer and the circle in another. This would allow you to leverage the animation capabilities of [Core Animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514). Core animation provides a simple and effective way to manipulate onscreen layers with implicit animations such as moving, resizing, changing colour etc.

Answer (score 0):

my guess, the `CGContextClearRect` call in your DrawBall method is the responsable of rectangles disappearing... From Apple documentation: *If the provided context is a window or bitmap context, Quartz effectively clears the rectangle.*

Comment: I remove it and nothing change. But it is not problem of setNeedsDisplay which causes redraw all uiview?

Comment: I see... I didn't understand the flow of your code sorry. Have you consider a different solution? you should use sublayers instead of drawing rects/circles: this way you can easyly add/remove them, change z-order and so on...